# Managing CATALINA_BASE with Maven

Tags: maven, tomcat

I am responsible for multiple Tomcat instances serving different applications.

My installation paradigm is that CATALINA_HOME is an unmodified version of Tomcat.

Within CATALINA_BASE are the customizations for our environment, bin/service.bat, conf/server.xml, lib/*.jars.

I would like to be able to manage these customizations through Maven under source control. I've set up Git for the source control but can any guide me toward this goal, a project structure like so:

```
MyTomcats
   /src
     /AppServer1
       /bin
          service.bat
          README.TXT
       /conf
          server.xml
   /pom.xml 
   /target
      /AppServer1.zip
      /AppServer1
         /bin
            service.bat
            README.TXT
         /conf
            server.xml
            ...
         /lib
            *.jars
         /webapps
            *.war
         /(other dirs)
```

The output of a mvn package would be a the CATALINA_BASE with the lib/*jars populated. I'm not too concerned about populating the webapp folder with the correct wars but I would like the necessary folder structure so that I could deliver a zipped CATALINA_BASE to operations when there are server updates.

I know that server updates aren't as frequent as application updates, but we are migrating from an embarassingly old JSP server to Tomcat and I can see myself quickly losing track of the situation if I don't manage the changes to CATALINA_BASE properly.

Comment: Have you looked into using Assembly plugin?

Comment: Maven doesn't look like a good fit here, why not simply store the CATALINA_BASE file structure in Git and then have a separate project for building the JARs? Also, instead of zipping, consider handing out a Git clone URL to operations and have them git pull in the layout upon updates.

Comment: Thanks, Noah(lz), I am experimenting with the Assembly plugin and I am have everything I need except the dependent jars (db2, Axis, etc) for the server/lib folder. The dependencyIncludes in the Assembly plugin assume that you are "including" from an existing build. I want that include to function like the dependency in a pom.

Comment: That's a good thought, Jukka, but having operations use Git is a deal stopper. Trying to get the DEVELOPERS around here to use git has been struggle enough and I've only made one convert from VSS so far.